# How can we use specific Color Scheme as PlotStyle in Plot

Tags: plotting, color, legending

My objective is to use `Plot` with an arbitrary `Color Scheme` to get something like this

[image]

but I want to use any color scheme such as:

1. a build-in scheme such as  `Rainbow`
2. or customize once such as

.

```
BarLegend[{{Darker@Red, Red, Lighter@Gray, Blue, Darker@Blue}, {1, 
   11}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

Here is my try:

```
dats = Table[n Sin[ x], {n, 1, 11}];
plot = Plot[dats, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], Frame -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> 50, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Note that it is not working as desired, each plot should have the same color but it is coloring according to the y-axis.

For the customized color scheme mentioned above cant do it, any help, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method-1

Use `ParametricPlot` and the tricks by @kglr (but I cann't find the original links now)

```
/. {(VertexColors -> None) -> VertexColors -> Automatic}
```

```
ParametricPlot[{x, n Sin[ x]}, {n, 1, 11}, {x, -π, π}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> False] /. {(VertexColors -> None) -> 
   VertexColors -> Automatic}
```

[image]

### Method-2

Extract colors from `ColorData` and use `PlotStyle`.

```
Clear[dats, colors];
dats = Table[n Sin[x], {n, 1, 11}];
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 11]
plot = Plot[dats, {x, -π, π}, Frame -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> 50, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> colors]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe It should be a more elegant way to do that using plot

Comment: Thanks a lot @cvgmt, That is EXACTLY what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively

```
Show[
Table[Plot[n Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][n/11]  ] , {n,1, 11}]
,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]